# I am using Proclipsing in Eclipse trying to draw an image to the screen

Tags: java, processing

I keep getting an error while trying to draw an image to the screen. The program works fine until I try to draw the image. I am using Processing version 3.3.7.

```
package test;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Test extends PApplet {

    PImage pic;

    public void setup() {
        pic = loadImage("test.png");
    }

    public void draw() {
        background(255,255,255);
        image(pic,0,0)
    }

    public void settings() {
        size(800,600);
    }

    public static void main(String _args[]) {
        PApplet.main(new String[] { test.Test.class.getName() });
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting after running it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at test.Test.main(Test.java:22)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
import processing.core.PImage;
```

You forgot a semi-colon on this line:

```
image(pic,0,0)
```